# mod_wsgi in apache not rendering html root properly

Tags: python-3.x, apache, mod-wsgi

I have the following python script that pulls in my index.html, which will eventually be split into a header.html, a footer.html and then python code will make up the body. How do I tell python to make the site directory the root directory for all html and html related files so css and the img folder render properly?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os

def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    localpath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    index_file = 'index.html'
    index_path = os.path.join(localpath, "adminUI", index_file)
    with open(index_path, 'rb') as index:
        output = index.read()
    #output = b'Hello World!\n'
    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/html'),
                ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)
    return [output]
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, adding Alias' to the virtual httpd.conf fixed the issue:

```
Alias /img /usr/local/apache2/site/img
Alias ../vendors /usr/local/apache2/vendors
```